# Pyspark rdd.join() struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

Tags: pyspark, rdd

file1 = sc.textFile("add1").map(json.loads)
file2 = sc.textFile("add2").map(json.loads)

file1_group = file1.map(lambda x: (x["key"],x["value"])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x)
file2_group = file2.map(lambda x: (x["key"],[x])).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)

files_group = file1_group.join(file2_group)

I don't know why "struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647" pop out.
file1_group should be [(key,value),(key,value),...]
file2_group should be [(key,[doc1,doc2,...]), .....]

When I join two group together, shouldn't be [(key,(value,[doc1,doc2,...])),...]?
I'm not sure why give me Pyspark rdd.join() struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647